I can't execute a query with SQLAlchemy using AsyncSession
I'm studying FastAPI and I can't understand how asynchronous requests to SQLAlchemy work.

database.py

from typing import AsyncIterator, AsyncGenerator
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine, AsyncSession
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from sqlalchemy import text
import os

load_dotenv()

DATABASE_URL = f"postgresql+asyncpg://{os.getenv('POSTGRES_USER')}:{os.getenv('POSTGRES_PASSWORD')}@{os.getenv('POSTGRES_HOST')}:{os.getenv('POSTGRES_PORT')}/{os.getenv('POSTGRES_DB')}"
engine = create_async_engine(DATABASE_URL)
async_session_maker = sessionmaker(engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False)

async def get_async_session() -> AsyncGenerator[AsyncSession, None]:
    async with async_session_maker() as session:
        yield session

async def check_db_connect():
        session = get_async_session()
        try:
            await session.execute(text("SELECT 1"))
            print("-- Database connection successful! --")
            await session.close()
            await engine.dispose()

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Database connection failed: {e}")

main.py

from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn
from app.routers.health_check import router
from app.core.config import settings
from app.db.database import check_db_connect

app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(router)

@app.on_event("startup")
async def on_startup():
    await check_db_connect()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run('app.main:app', host=settings.HOST, port=settings.PORT, reload=settings.RELOAD)

My idea is to call async def get_async_session() where I need it and work with the database. However, I'm getting the error 'async_generator' object has no attribute 'execute.
I expect to get a session from an async_generator.

get_async_session() is defined as async, so you need to await it. If you're not comfortable writing async code (which requires cooperation from you), just drop the async parts - FastAPI will run the code automagically in a threadpool for you instead.

async with get_async_session() as session:

And, you don't need to call session.close() and engine.dispose() since  you use context manager to create session
